# employer - employee contracting in the private sector in Argentina

Tags: inflation, argentina

Argentina has high and volatile inflation and a history of it, so people have had time to adapt.

[image: graph]

I am interested in particular adaptations around contracts for "permanent" full time workers engaged in a long term project or serving a long term need for private sector companies. An example would be a project manager or a software engineer or a department manager. Do the workers and employers simply write the contract in USD or do they engage in frequent re-assessments as to whether the compensation is acceptable to both parties?